# java csv multiple data parsing

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have String as:

```
String cont = "[[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,13.46,\"1682432\"]," +
                    "[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,-13.46,\"1682432\"]," +
                    "[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,-14.52,\"1682432\"]," +
                    "[\"START\",\"6002\",\"020\",\"0000000PWO\",\"2014-07-15\",\"MY Comment - FICA and\",-13.46,0,\"1682432\"]," +
                    "[\"START\",\"6002\",\"020\",\"0000000PWO\",\"2014-07-15\",\"MY Comment - FEED\",-1.06,0,\"1682432\"]" +
                "]";
```

I need output as

```
Account || Date ||        Amount || Description ||          InvoiceNo
1001     2014-07-15       -13.46                            1682432
....some more data
6002     2014-07-15       -1.06    MY desc                  1682432
```

I am trying to use Apache CSV parser with version 2.3.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

java code:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(cont), ',');
List<String[]> records = reader.readAll();
Iterator<String[]> iterator = records.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String[] record  =  iterator.next();
    for (String string : record) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

output:

```
[[START 
1001  
2014-07-15

...

["START
6002
020
0000000PWO
2014-07-15
MY Comment - FEED
-1.06
0
1682432"]]
```

1) How do I remove the special character "[" and "]"

2) How do I assign values to above output fields

3) I want to convert above csv to bean object

4) bean to json

Comment: I think you're actually using [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net). Yes, it happens to be under Apache license, but there is also [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) which is the CSV library by The Apache Software Foundation. As a side note, I can warmly recommend Commons CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the open source library uniVocity-parsers to convert csv to bean objects, just as following code shows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    /**
     * ---------------------------------------------
     *  Read CSV rows into list of beans you defined
     * ---------------------------------------------
     */
    // 1st, config the CSV reader with row processor attaching the bean definition
    BeanListProcessor<ColumnBean> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<ColumnBean>(ColumnBean.class);
    settings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    // 2nd, parse all rows from the CSV file into the list of beans you defined
    parser.parse(new StringReader(cont));
    List<ColumnBean> resolvedBeans = rowProcessor.getBeans();

    // 3rd, process the beans with business logic
    // ......
}
```

With the library, you only need several lines of code, and it also provides significent performance. Find tutorials at its [Homepage.](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)

As per the convert from bean object to json, you can check the [Google Gson project.](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 0):

For **2)**, use `System.out.print`, instead of `println` (this just prints the string without a new line at the end), and concatenate tabs (`\t`) to your data values.  You will need to break up your `string` variable into multiple parts to achieve this.  Tabs will allow you to align them in proper rows appropriately.

Once your string is in multiple parts, for **1)** you will want to slice the first character from the first "piece" and the last character from the last piece.  This will remove the first `[` and the last `]`.  I suggest using `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the special characters I used a regexp for all special characters except "-" which you strings seems to contain. If more characters are to be kept , refactor that to a special set and just append it to the regexp.

For assigning values I'm not really sure what you want to do, I guess you want a String variable in the code for either a line or a ,ABCXYZ,. If you want to construct a string dynamically from a whole line use a StringBuilder or StringBuffer. I came up with this code for parsing

```
String cont = "[[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,13.46,\"1682432\"]," +
            "[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,-13.46,\"1682432\"]," +
            "[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,-14.52,\"1682432\"]," +
            "[\"START\",\"6002\",\"020\",\"0000000PWO\",\"2014-07-15\",\"MY Comment - FICA and\",-13.46,0,\"1682432\"]," +
            "[\"START\",\"6002\",\"020\",\"0000000PWO\",\"2014-07-15\",\"MY Comment - FEED\",-1.06,0,\"1682432\"]" +
            "]";

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(cont), ',');
    List<String[]> records = reader.readAll();
    Iterator<String[]> iterator = records.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String[] record = iterator.next();

        for (String string : record) {
            string = string.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\-]", "");
            if (string.startsWith("START")) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print(string);
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use any csv parser jars 
Just use the below code

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
   String cont = "[[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,13.46,\"1682432\"]," +
                "[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,-13.46,\"1682432\"]," +
                "[\"START\",\"1001\",\"\",\"\",\"2014-07-15\",\"Invoice\",0,-14.52,\"1682432\"]," +
                "[\"START\",\"6002\",\"020\",\"0000000PWO\",\"2014-07-15\",\"MY Comment - FICA and\",-13.46,0,\"1682432\"]," +
                "[\"START\",\"6002\",\"020\",\"0000000PWO\",\"2014-07-15\",\"MY Comment - FEED\",-1.06,0,\"1682432\"]" +
            "]";

    String[] csvArry = cont.split(",");      
    for (String value : csvArry) {
        value = value.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\-]", "");
        System.out.println(value); 
    }
}
```

It will do everything which you want.
Hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For transformation of CSV to beans use https://github.com/CyborTronik/fluent-ssv

You are also able to write your line parser(where you will throw unecesary chars) by implementing LineParser and provide it to SsvStreamBuilder.

That's it